# Can't properly format numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to format numbers in a table, through a formatter, in a way that the thousands are separated by commas, and the decimals by a dot.

I've set up the following formatter function, which can handle non-numeric values and possible, faily null-values:

```
  this.table.formatter = (val, col) => {

    const numberWithCommas = (x, decimals) => {
      var parts = x.toString().split(".");
      parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
      if(parts[1]){
        parts[1] = Number(parts[1]).toFixed(decimals);
      } 
      return decimals > 0 ? parts.join(".") : parts[0];
    }

    let res;
    if (col == "period" || col == "channel") {
      res = isNaN(val) ? val : " ";
      return res;
    } else {
      const decimals = this.config.data.metric["format"]["decimals"] | 0;

      if (val != null) {
        if (!isNaN(val)) {
          res = numberWithCommas(val, decimals);
        } else {
          res = val;
        }

        return res != " " ? this.config.data.metric["format"].prefix + " " + res + " " + this.config.data.metric["format"].postfix : "";
      }else{
        return "";
      }
    }

  }
```

For numbers without decimals (numbers in which the variable "decimals" is 0) it works perfectly and separates the numbers by a comma. But for decimals, the results are horrible and make absolutely no sense:

[image]

edit:

This is an example raw data packet for two rows, so you can see how the original data looks like. In these cases, they are float numbers with a huge number of decimals:

[image]

Do you have any idea on what's failing here? Thanks!

Comment: Does always fraction part contain `00`?

Comment: @revo Not in the raw data at least!

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel, use [`Number.prototype.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString).

Comment: @str I have the requirement of using commas as thousands separator instead of dot...

Comment: Then read the documentation and see how you would do that.

Answer (score 1):

Bellow code worked for me

```
var N = 1000;

console.log(N.toLocaleString());
```

You can refer to the same at [numObj.toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

Answer (score 0):

A mixture of all the comments/answers received, and a little read to the documentation, allowed me to find the way:

```
res = val.toLocaleString("en-IN", {maximumFractionDigits: decimals, minimumFractionDigits: decimals});
```

Using the ".toLocaleString()" method by itself, wouldn't put the thousands separator as commas, because I'm at Spain. But setting the "en-IN" locale, started putting them as separators. Then, using the options located at the documentation, I could easily set up a fixed amount of decimals.

Now it works great. Thanks to everyone!